# Vba Excel: Is it possible to Clone Form Control?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to generate hundreds of form control dropdowns with same item values. So i would like to clone them if possible. And i should be able to change few attributes like **Name, OnAction** Any ideas would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Create them programmatically (i.e. at run-time rather than design-time).

Comment: I would give @steve040 an upvote on his answer if he posted some working code.  Creating controls at runtime is not easy so an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim c As Range, i As Long, nm As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    i = 0
    For Each c In sht.Range("A2:A20")
        i = i + 1
        nm = "dd_" & i
        On Error Resume Next
        sht.Shapes(nm).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0

        With sht.DropDowns.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height)
            .Name = nm
            .ListFillRange = "K1:K6"
            .LinkedCell = ""
            .DropDownLines = 8
            .Display3DShading = False
            .OnAction = "HandleClick"
        End With

    Next c

End Sub
```

Handler:

```
Sub HandleClick()
    Debug.Print Application.Caller
End Sub
```

Comment: code is working fine but i want to know whether the form controls cloning is possible?

Comment: I think your only option might be via copy/paste, which is not very tidy.